# how to check using selenium webdriver if dot characters are being displayed in password field of the open page?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have to perform an automated testing for which i need to check whether the text in password field is being displayed or is it marked by some characters. How can i check that on Chrome using selenium web driver?

Comment: You need to check that the property of the field is marked as `password`. That is all that you can do directly. Indirectly, you can take a screen shot of the field after putting some characters in to it and finding a way to compare just the field with a reference image.

Comment: Thanks I checked its type being marked as password or not.. It worked perfectly well for me..